# Can somebody please correct my understanding of how ViewDataDictionary works?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Can somebody correct my understanding of what's going on here?

Suppose the following:

```
<% foreach (var company in Model.Companies) { %>

    <% Html.RenderPartial("FundList", Model, new ViewDataDictionary(company)); %>

<% } %>
```

I was under the impression that this will render a Partial View called `FundList.ascx`, while passing a `Model` object (which contains a load of stuff), and also a `company` object, which contains data specific to a company.

However, when I inspect the data available to me in `FundList`, I can only see references to the original `Model` object. I don't see `company` anywhere. Should this be available in `ViewData`?

How would it be best for me to get a `company` object in the `FundData` partial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try...

```
   <% Html.RenderPartial(
          "FundList", 
          Model, 
          new ViewDataDictionary { { "company", company } }); %>
```

Answer (score 1):

your partial should inherit from type `ViewPage<Company>` and then you can pass the current company direct as viewmodel.
The ViewDataDictionary of the hosting page will passover to the partial automatically.

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("FundList", company); %>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about just moving the foreach into your partial view, removing the need for this viewdata? Looks like the cleanest solution to me.

If not, are you sure you actually need the "Model"? Isn't the company supposed to be your model while the other stuff should not be concerning the partial view?

Otherwise, go for a viewmodel containing all properties needed.